# How to set generic type at runtime in java

Tags: java, generics, runtime

I saw some questions like this but different from my case.I want to set generated class at build time as generic type at runtime.
here is code.

```
  //employee class is generated at build time 
  void function(Class<?> employee)
  {  
      // I want to set class as generic type like this 
     List<employee> emps= new ArrayList<employee>(employee);
   }
```

how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Class<T> employee, ...` and then `BeanListProcessor<T>` maybe?

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you?

Comment: Let the function signature be `<T> void function(Class<T> employee, String csvFile)` and then use `BeanListProcessor<T>` instead of `BeanListProcessor<employee>`. (not sure this is what you're after though).

Comment: Your question is really unclear, what is your use-case? What is `BeanListProcessor`? What do you want to do?

Comment: What are you going to do with this list after you create it?  I suspect you want something like `<T> void function(Class<T> klass)` but it's hard to tell from your description.

Comment: I am generation pojo classes at build time from csv header and I am passing that class into this function. that class I want to set as generic type of BeanListProcessor from that I will able to read csv data and direclty map to the pojo class

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Generics are all mapped to `java.lang.Object` on compilation by a process called *type erasure*.

You can only build things that are checked at compile time: consider using `Class<? extends ...>` notation.

Comment: actully, I am generation pojo classes at build time and I am passing that class into this function. then that class I want to set as generic type of BeanListProcessor.  is there any another way?

Comment: No.  Generics do not exist at runtime, no matter how you try to work around it.  There wouldn't even be any meaning to trying to create generics at runtime.